# gcloud command suddenly doesn't work at all

Tags: google-cloud-platform

All `gcloud` commands suddenly give this error:

> ERROR: gcloud failed to load: No module named google.appengine.ext
>
> This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or
>   problems with your Python interpreter.
>
> Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7
>   executable:
>       /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
>
> If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to
>   point to a working Python 2.7 executable.
>
> If you are still experiencing problems, please reinstall the Cloud SDK
>   using the instructions here:
>       https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Here are some relevant details and things that I've tried:

- Mac 10.11.6
- Python 2.7.8 at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
- Python otherwise works fine
- I completely removed google-cloud-sdk and redownloaded from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/
- Tried rebooting
- Tried "export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python" but it didn't help.  Also added this line to my .bash_profile

Anyone else having this problem or can suggest a fix?

---

I have a fix below, but I'll happily award the answer to anyone who can explain what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the problem, though I don't understand what is going on...  When reinstalling `gcloud` I skipped the install script (`./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh`) since it is an optional step and I already had the needed lines in my bash profile.

When running this script, however, I got this error:

```
$ ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 8, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/Users/.../google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 17, in <module>
    import oauth2client.contrib.gce as gce
  File "/Users/.../google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/oauth2client/contrib/gce.py", line 23, in <module>
    import httplib2
  File "/Users/.../google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/httplib2/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import email
  File "/Users/.../GIT/GAE_Project/email.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named google.appengine.ext
```

A file I recently created in my GAE project named `email.py` broke `gcloud`!?!  Renaming this file fixed `gcloud`.

This is my PYTHONPATH:

```
/Users/.../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine:/Users/.../GIT/GAE_Project
```

So even though the Google cloud libraries come before my GAE project in my PYTHONPATH, a file in my GAE project broke `gcloud`.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue . I solved it by using the default python2.7 in Ubuntu

Type this in termimal

```
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
```

Not sure if this will work the same on Windows

Comment: This didn't work for me at first. I had to use "whereis python" command, and that got me this path: "/usr/bin/python2.7". So I used it in the export command and it worked!

Answer (score 5):

I followed the answer here, worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59816812/2210667

`brew switch openssl 1.0.2q` (or whatever latest version you have from `ls /usr/local/Cellar/openssl`)